# Using firestore with vue to get image url

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to firebase storage. I've been able to use firestore with documents using VUE, but I'm using storage for images.

I'm getting continual errors and I believe it relates to failing to create the reference as required.

Questions:

1. Firebase storage requires a "ref" function. How do I import that per firebase documentation in a way that doesn't conflict with the vue "ref" function? My attempt is below, but it's not working.
2. As currently set up below, I get an error 0 , *firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_.storageRef) is not a function. I can't figure out how to overcome this--I keep going through documentation and reviewing videos, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Here is the config setup:

```
 import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
 import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
 import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  [Info]
};

// init firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init firestore service
const db = getFirestore();

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to 
create references in your storage bucket
const storage = getStorage(initializeApp(firebaseConfig));

const storageRef = ref(storage);

export { db, storage, storageRef };
```

Here is the Vue setup:

```
 import { computed, ref } from "vue";
 

 //firebase imports
 import { db, storage, storageRef } from 
  "../../firebase/config"; 
 import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
 import { getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

export default {
name: "Name",


setup() {

const imagesRef = storageRef(storage);



getDownloadURL(imagesRef).then((url) => {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
  console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias) when importing the ref function required by Firebase Storage and distinguish it from the required by Vue.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage, ref as refStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  [Info]
};

// init firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init firestore service
const db = getFirestore();

const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
const storageRef = refStorage(storage);

export { db, storage, storageRef };

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

I have used [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to test the above code and added the following versions of Firebase dependencies to the package.json file:

```
"@firebase/storage": "0.9.0"
"firebase": "9.6.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

**Firebase config:**

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    // ...   
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

export { db, storage };
```

**Vue.js component:**

```js
// ...
<script>
import { db, storage } from '../../firebase/config';  // Import db only if you need to use Firestore in this component
import {
  collection,
  // ...
} from 'firebase/firestore';  // Idem, only if you need to use Firestore in this component

import {
  ref,
  getDownloadURL,
  // ...
} from 'firebase/storage';

export default {
  // ...
  data: () => ({
    // ...
  }),
  methods: {
    async uploadFile(file) {
      try {
        const fileName = file.name;

        const fileRef = ref(storage, `myFolder/${fileName}`);

        // ....
```

Comment: Hi Renaud! Thank you for your help. I think your config structure worked. I'm using the Vue Setup API, which requires an imported ref funciton from vue, and that conflicts with the firestore import. Should I (a) try to import the vue ref globally, (b) put the firebase import in the config file, or (c) do something else?